# Does chrome removes offline content if not accessed?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, offline-caching

I have developed a `PWA` so it works both online and offline (app icon gets added to mobile homescreen) . I store the last synch timestamp to incrementally update mobile client data. Data is stored in indexedDB (Dexie.js), store the synchtime in `localStorage` all works well until I access the application regularly. I did not access the aap for two days, when tried to open the app from Homescreen Icon on my Android device it says "i need to connect to internet for first load" so far so good, but, I see no saved data when the app is loaded.

ideally if the app is a fresh load (new device on), it will fetch data from remote server based on the synch timestamp as `null`, but here i see `localStorage` still keeps the timestamp and other details like login keys(token) intact, came to know after checked the request log at back-end, but IndedexDB content expired.

However, some collections stores data on the desktop (laptop) chrome version in the same situation. Am I missing something here ? The table definition is similar for all tables though.

what event in service worker determines the content expiry so it pops the message " you need to connect to internet" ? I will clear all content including local storage then

Answer (score 0):

You can register a route in the service worker and set the cache expiration.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    '/myfile.js',
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: CODE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60; //5 days,
        }),
    ],
})
```